Matplotlib Pyplot Bar Missing Data (aliasing)
I recently had a problem with aliasing when plotting high-density data using the matplotlib pyplot bar function. Chunks of data appear missing in the plot despite actually being there. The below example takes around 40 seconds to run on my medium spec laptop.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3)
ax1 = axes[0]
ax2 = axes[1]
ax3 = axes[2]

#Get some high-density data
raw=np.abs(np.random.normal(10000,1000,2000000).astype(np.int16))
counts=np.bincount(raw)
bins=np.arange(len(counts))


#Three different ways to plot the histogram
ax1.bar(bins, counts)
ax2.bar(bins, counts, width=1)
ax3.fill_between(bins, counts, step='mid') #Setting step='mid' centres the bars on the data


#Tidy up and plot
ax3.set_ylim(bottom=0)
for ax in axes: ax.set_xlim(5000, 15000)
ax1.set_title("plt.bar")
ax2.set_title("plt.bar, width=1")
ax3.set_title("plt.fill_between, step='mid'")
fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('norm.png', dpi=600)
plt.savefig("norm.svg",format='svg') #vector graphics means all data is represented in the image
plt.show()

matplotlib pyplot bar showing aliasing
After a little digging, I found possible solutions and will self-answer this question.
I am hoping for some accurate way of displaying the data.

This is an aliasing problem because there are got more data points than pixels to represent them. It's made particularly visible due to whitespace. The plot can be made to look nicer by setting an appropriate value for the "width" argument of bar() so that there is no whitespace between bars. Here I use width=1 (the default is 0.8). The code below takes around 40 seconds to run on my medium spec laptop.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3)
ax1 = axes[0]
ax2 = axes[1]
ax3 = axes[2]

#Get some high-density data
raw=np.abs(np.random.normal(10000,1000,2000000).astype(np.int16))
counts=np.bincount(raw)
bins=np.arange(len(counts))


#Three different ways to plot the histogram
ax1.bar(bins, counts)
ax2.bar(bins, counts, width=1)
ax3.fill_between(bins, counts, step='mid') #Setting step='mid' centres the bars on the data


#Tidy up and plot
ax3.set_ylim(bottom=0)
for ax in axes: ax.set_xlim(5000, 15000)
ax1.set_title("plt.bar")
ax2.set_title("plt.bar, width=1")
ax3.set_title("plt.fill_between, step='mid'")
fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('norm.png')
plt.savefig("norm.svg",format='svg') #vector graphics means all data is represented in the image
plt.show()

matplotlib pyplot image aliasing
Other keyword arguments one might want to pass to plyplot.bar are linewidth=0 and edgecolor=None to ensure the no edges are drawn on the bars.
An alternative is to use a different plotting tool such as plt.fill_between or plt.step or plt.stairs. I chose to use fill_between as the other two options made filling the bars difficult.
Please note, even once we've made the whitespace aliasing disappear, we still have the issue that there are more data points than pixels to represent them. One should investigate how this will be rendered - if the values are being averaged, this will smooth the data and hide fluctuations that you may be trying to catch.
